# Click elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, slider

Trying to make a simple loop for a carousel to slide the images automatic but can't figure out why it doesnt work... Any help is appreciated, (the 'dot' is what you click at when you want to change picture in the carousel) but I want the slides to change automatically when the page is visited.

the code looks like this:

```
window.setInterval(slideClick, 2000);

var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');

    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        function slideClick() {
        slides.click();

        }
    }

    if (i === slides.lenght) {
        i=0;
    }
```

I get this error: Object # has no method 'click'

and if I change slides.click(); to the classname $('.dot').click it works but only for the two first slides?

Answer (score 3):

- [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) which you use to obtain slides returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList), it's a list of nodes, not a single element.
- [`HTMLElement#click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click) is a method of a single element. You can iterate the returned `NodeList` and call it on each returned value.

One way is:

```
for(var j = 0; j < slides.length; j++) slides[j].click();
```

Comment: slides just turn up as undefined, dont know why?

Comment: @spovell make sure you put your scripts at the end of your body section just before `</body>`

Comment: acctually it worked but the same problem with the carousel only shuffles the two first images over and over

Comment: @spovell go on jsfiddle.net and create a __short self contained__ sample of your code.

Comment: The script is where it should be, I made it this far before aswell, so the problem is it doesnt reach more than one image then it goes back again, dont understand why...

Comment: the slider contains large amounts of javascript code and libraries and so on, cant make a jsfiddle that would make any difference than what you see...

Comment: the problem lies in the array or nodelist, the consol can log the entire list of elements but only if I log it outside of the loop, inside the loop it seems it cant find more than one element...